# Random Generator Code?

Tags: c#, random, xna

I'm trying to get this code to produce an array comprising unique random musical notes. It will, based on parameters given make a note and assign an accidental sign to it, with a possibility of either displaying as its flat or sharp counterpart. For example, if the random generator said the note "A" will be flat, there's a chance it will show up as either A♭ or G♯.

Now, I haven't handled the half-step notes (e.g. C♭ is turned into B♯, etc.), but that's mainly because the first part isn't working. The problem I have now is the code I'm using doesn't seem to work consistently. It will correctly translate the notes at some times and mess them up on others. There's no systematic pattern of error, either, at least, not from I've tried to decipher.

I'm using XNA for this to display the notes on the screen, but the real problem is with the data. I'm using a `Note` class I made.

Here's the code I'm using:

First the `Note` class:

```
 public class Note
    {
        public enum Notes
        {
            A = 0,
            B = 1,
            C = 2,
            D = 3,
            E = 4,
            F = 5,
            G = 6
        }
        public Notes noteLetter { get; private set; }
        public Notes translatedLetter { get; private set; }
        public bool isFlat { get; private set; }
        public bool showSharp { get; private set; }

        private const int NOTE_COUNT = 7;

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a Note
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="note">The basic note</param>
        /// <param name="flat">Is the note flat?</param>
        /// <param name="sharp">Will be shown as it's sharp counterpart?</param>
        public Note(Notes note, bool flat, bool sharp)
        {
            noteLetter = note;
            isFlat = flat;
            showSharp = sharp;

            if (isFlat && showSharp)
            {
                int hashCode = (int)noteLetter;
                translatedLetter = (Notes)((hashCode + NOTE_COUNT - 1) % NOTE_COUNT);
            }
            else
            {
                translatedLetter = noteLetter;
                showSharp = isFlat;
            }

        }
    }
```

Then the Game1.cs file:

```
 public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        KeyboardState KeyBState, prevKeybState;

        Texture2D sprite;

        Rectangle noteSource;
        Rectangle accSource;

        const int ACCIDENTAL_START_X = 840;

        const int BORDER_OFFSET = 12;

        Vector2 notePosition;

        SpriteFont font;

        /// <summary>
        /// The array of notes, row/column format
        /// </summary>
        Note[,] box;

        const int ROW_SIZE = 3, COLUMN_SIZE = 4;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

            box = new Note[ROW_SIZE, COLUMN_SIZE];
            noteSource = new Rectangle(0, 0, 120, 120);
            accSource = new Rectangle(ACCIDENTAL_START_X, 0, 50, 50);

            notePosition = Vector2.Zero;
        }


        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
            MakeTable();

            base.Initialize();
        }


        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            sprite = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Note Pieces2");
            font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("font");
            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }


        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }


        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            KeyBState = Keyboard.GetState();

            if (KeyBState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                this.Exit();

            if (KeyBState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && prevKeybState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Space))
                MakeTable();

            // TODO: Add your update logic here
            prevKeybState = KeyBState;
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }


        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            // TODO: Add your drawing code here
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            for (int r = 0; r < ROW_SIZE; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < COLUMN_SIZE; c++)
                {
                    Note temp = box[r, c];
                    notePosition.Y = r * noteSource.Width + (r * BORDER_OFFSET);
                    notePosition.X = c * noteSource.Height + (c * BORDER_OFFSET);
                    noteSource.X = temp.translatedLetter.GetHashCode() * noteSource.Width;

                    spriteBatch.Draw(sprite, notePosition, noteSource, Color.White);

                    notePosition.X += noteSource.Width / 2;
                    notePosition.Y += 7;

                    spriteBatch.DrawString(font,
                        temp.noteLetter.ToString() +
                        (temp.isFlat ? "b " : "  ") +
                        temp.translatedLetter +
                        (temp.showSharp ? "#" : ""), notePosition, Color.Black);

                    notePosition.X -= noteSource.Width / 2;
                    notePosition.Y -= 7;

                    if (temp.isFlat)
                    {
                        notePosition.X += 63;
                        notePosition.Y += 63;

                        accSource.X = ACCIDENTAL_START_X;
                        accSource.Y = 0;
                        if (temp.showSharp)
                        {
                            accSource.X += (temp.translatedLetter.GetHashCode() % 2) * (accSource.Width * 2);
                            accSource.Y += ((int)(temp.translatedLetter.GetHashCode() / 2)) * accSource.Height;
                            spriteBatch.Draw(sprite, notePosition, accSource, Color.White);
                        }
                        /*
                    else
                    {
                        accSource.X += (temp.translatedLetter.GetHashCode() % 2) * (accSource.Width * 2) + accSource.Width;
                        accSource.Y += ((int)(temp.translatedLetter.GetHashCode() / 2)) * accSource.Height;
                        spriteBatch.Draw(sprite, notePosition, accSource, Color.White);
                    }
                    */
                    }

                }
            }
            spriteBatch.End();
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Makes a new random table of notes
        /// </summary>
        private void MakeTable()
        {
            //make everything null
            for (int r = 0; r < ROW_SIZE; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < COLUMN_SIZE; c++)
                {
                    box[r, c] = null;
                }
            }

            //then start
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            {
                bool isUnique;
                bool noteEntered;

                do
                {
                    Note newNote = new Note((Note.Notes)rand.Next(0, 7),
                                rand.Next(0, 2) == 0 ? true : false,
                                rand.Next(0, 2) == 0 ? true : false);

                    isUnique = true;
                    noteEntered = false;
                    //Check to see if there exists a note like this
                    for (int r = 0; r < ROW_SIZE; r++)
                    {
                        for (int c = 0; c < COLUMN_SIZE; c++)
                        {
                            Note temp = box[r, c];
                            if (noteEntered || !isUnique)
                                continue;
                            else if (temp != null &&
                                temp.noteLetter == newNote.noteLetter &&
                                temp.isFlat == newNote.isFlat)
                            {
                                isUnique = false;
                            }
                            else if (temp == null)
                            {
                                box[r, c] = newNote;
                                noteEntered = true;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                } while (!isUnique);
            }
        }
    }
```

The main code running everything is the `MakeTable()` method, but I put in everything just in case there's a problem somewhere else. To the best of my knowledge, other than graphics libraries, I'm not using any libraries related to the XNA Framework that would cause this to go wrong. I'm using a rebuild of XNA made by CodePlex. I know they're still working on some things, but this shouldn't be an issue. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Why does your enum not specify integer values? that cast might be a problem.

Comment: An error in the note class: calling GetHashCode can result in a random number, don't do it. Another error: you have too bools in the note class and its constructor, but with the current logic, they will always have the same value (if they are not the same, then the showSharp=isFlat assignment makes them equal). And the most problematic part with this question is that you should tell us the actual vs expected results. I really have no idea what you're trying to achieve here, and I don't understand musical notes either.

Comment: So one at a time. I didn't know about the GetHashCode() being an issue. I've used it before, and I didn't have this problem until now. However, I'm willing to stop using it. As for showSharp and isFlat: I have a reason for both. Just in case you don't know, sharp and flat doesn't work like positive and negative; there are three values: sharp, natural (no sharp or flat), and flat. Each note has a possibility of being either one of these values, aside from natural keys that are a half step away from each other. In those cases, their relative sharps and flat translate to being each other. TBC

Comment: In the other cases, the sharp of one key is the same as the flat of the next key (e.g. C# = Db). Putting all this together, there are twelve different notes that you can have. That's why my 2D array is 4X3. Each one is supposed to have a different note inside it. However, they should be randomly placed, and controlled by the space bar so that I can make a new table whenever I press it. When the entire table is populated, it should represent each key in some way using either a sharp version, a flat version, or a natural version of the note, when and wherever appropriate. It's not doing that.

Comment: If you're using a standard Western 12-tone tempered chromatic scale (that is, you're considering C# to be the same note as Db), and you're not yet considering keys, then why start with an 8-value enum in the first place? Start with a 12-value enum; it will simplify things greatly. Also, you seem to be trying to fill a table with all the notes by generating them randomly, which is insane. You don't want random notes: you want all the notes, *in random order*, which you get much quicker by filling the array first and then shuffling.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker:...d'oh! Right! Thank you. I should've thought of that. I mean, I REALLY should have!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out now. I took Lee Daniel Crocker's advice, and fixed up my program. I made a 12-value enum, and I edited the `MakeTable()` method so that it pulls each note from a distinct set and feeds them randomly into another array. Additionally, I fixed up my picture so that I can draw it easier. In hindsight, even *I* don't know why I did what I originally did.

By the way, I moved `MakeTable()` to the `Note` class to make it easier to write `MakeTable()`.

Here's my code:

First, `Note`:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// A musical note
    /// </summary>
    public class Note
    {
        public enum Notes
        {
            Ab = 10,
            A = 0,
            Bb = 11,
            B = 1,
            C = 2,
            Db = 13,
            D = 3,
            Eb = 14,
            E = 4,
            F = 5,
            Gb = 16,
            G = 6
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// This holds the notes with accidentals
        /// </summary>
        public Notes noteLetter { get; private set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// this holds the note without any accidentals
        /// </summary>
        public Notes naturalLetter { get; private set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Holds the value of the note if showsharp is true
        /// </summary>
        public Notes translatedLetter { get; private set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Denotes whether or not the note will represented
        /// as its sharp counterpart, its prerequisite being
        /// that it was flat in the first place
        /// </summary>
        public bool showSharp { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a Note
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="note">The basic note</param>
        /// <param name="sharp">Will be shown as it's sharp counterpart?</param>
        public Note(Notes note, bool sharp)
        {
            noteLetter = note;
            switch(noteLetter)
            {
                case Notes.Ab:
                    naturalLetter = Notes.A;
                    translatedLetter = Notes.G;
                    break;
                case Notes.Bb:
                    naturalLetter = Notes.B;
                    translatedLetter = Notes.A;
                    break;
                case Notes.Db:
                    naturalLetter = Notes.D;
                    translatedLetter = Notes.C;
                    break;
                case Notes.Eb:
                    naturalLetter = Notes.E;
                    translatedLetter = Notes.D;
                    break;
                case Notes.Gb:
                    naturalLetter = Notes.G;
                    translatedLetter = Notes.F;
                    break;
                default:
                    naturalLetter = noteLetter;
                    break;
            }
            showSharp = sharp;

            if (showSharp)
            {
                switch (noteLetter)
                {
                    case Notes.A:
                    case Notes.B:
                    case Notes.C:
                    case Notes.D:
                    case Notes.E:
                    case Notes.F:
                    case Notes.G:
                        showSharp = false;
                        break;
                }
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Will make a random table of Note objects
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="table">the array in which to place the Note objects</param>
        public static void MakeTable(out Note[,] table)
        {
            Note[,] temp = new Note[3, 4];

            Random rand = new Random();

            temp[0, 0] = new Note(Notes.Ab, (rand.Next(0, 2) == 0 ? true : false));
            temp[0, 1] = new Note(Notes.A, (rand.Next(0, 2) == 0 ? true : false));
            temp[0, 2] = new Note(Notes.Bb, (rand.Next(0, 2) == 0 ? true : false));
            temp[0, 3] = new Note(Notes.B, (rand.Next(0, 2) == 0 ? true : false));
            temp[1, 0] = new Note(Notes.C, (rand.Next(0, 2) == 0 ? true : false));
            temp[1, 1] = new Note(Notes.Db, (rand.Next(0, 2) == 0 ? true : false));
            temp[1, 2] = new Note(Notes.D, (rand.Next(0, 2) == 0 ? true : false));
            temp[1, 3] = new Note(Notes.Eb, (rand.Next(0, 2) == 0 ? true : false));
            temp[2, 0] = new Note(Notes.E, (rand.Next(0, 2) == 0 ? true : false));
            temp[2, 1] = new Note(Notes.F, (rand.Next(0, 2) == 0 ? true : false));
            temp[2, 2] = new Note(Notes.Gb, (rand.Next(0, 2) == 0 ? true : false));
            temp[2, 3] = new Note(Notes.G, (rand.Next(0, 2) == 0 ? true : false));

            table = new Note[3, 4];

            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            {
                int row;
                int col;

                row = rand.Next(0, 3);
                col = rand.Next(0, 4);

                while (table[row, col] != null)
                {
                    //Randomly choose if either the row or column will be incremented
                    bool useRow = (rand.Next(0, 2) == 0 ? true : false);

                    //then increment one of them
                    if (useRow)
                    {
                        row = (row + 1) % 3;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        col = (col + 1) % 4;
                    }
                }

                //Place notes in the empty registers
                if (table[row, col] == null)
                {
                    table[row, col] = temp[(int)(i / 4), i % 4];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And `Game1`:

```
/// <summary>
/// This is the main type for your game
/// </summary>
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    KeyboardState KeyBState, prevKeybState;

    Texture2D sprite;

    Rectangle noteSource;
    Rectangle accSource;

    const int ACCIDENTAL_START_X = 840;

    const int BORDER_OFFSET = 12;

    Vector2 notePosition;

    SpriteFont font;

    /// <summary>
    /// The array of notes, row/column format
    /// </summary>
    Note[,] box;

    const int ROW_SIZE = 3, COLUMN_SIZE = 4;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

        box = new Note[ROW_SIZE, COLUMN_SIZE];
        noteSource = new Rectangle(0, 0, 120, 120);
        accSource = new Rectangle(ACCIDENTAL_START_X, 0, 50, 50);

        notePosition = Vector2.Zero;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
        Note.MakeTable(out box);

        base.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        sprite = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Note Pieces2");
        font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("font");
        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        KeyBState = Keyboard.GetState();

        if (KeyBState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            this.Exit();

        if (KeyBState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && prevKeybState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Space))
            Note.MakeTable(out box);

        // TODO: Add your update logic here
        prevKeybState = KeyBState;
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        // TODO: Add your drawing code here
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        for (int r = 0; r < ROW_SIZE; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < COLUMN_SIZE; c++)
            {
                Note temp = box[r, c];
                notePosition.Y = r * noteSource.Width + ((r + 1) * BORDER_OFFSET);
                notePosition.X = c * noteSource.Height + ((c + 1) * BORDER_OFFSET);
                noteSource.X = (temp.showSharp ? (int)temp.translatedLetter : (int)temp.naturalLetter) * noteSource.Width;

                spriteBatch.Draw(sprite, notePosition, noteSource, Color.White);

                notePosition.X += noteSource.Width / 2;
                notePosition.Y += 7;

                spriteBatch.DrawString(font,
                    temp.noteLetter.ToString() + " " +
                    (temp.showSharp ? "#" : ""), notePosition, Color.Black);

                notePosition.X -= noteSource.Width / 2;
                notePosition.Y -= 7;

                switch (temp.noteLetter)
                {
                    case Note.Notes.Ab:
                    case Note.Notes.Bb:
                    case Note.Notes.Db:
                    case Note.Notes.Eb:
                    case Note.Notes.Gb:
                        notePosition.X += 63;
                        notePosition.Y += 63;

                        int accOffset = 0;
                        if (temp.showSharp)
                        {
                            accSource.X = (int)temp.translatedLetter * noteSource.Width;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            accSource.X = (int)temp.naturalLetter * noteSource.Width;
                            accOffset = accSource.Width;
                        }

                        accSource.X += accOffset;
                        accSource.Y = noteSource.Height;
                        spriteBatch.Draw(sprite, notePosition, accSource, Color.White);
                        break;
                }

            }
        }
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
      }
    }
```